# custom builder product option magento extension

Tags: module

My client website want to build Custom product builder similar to this website: http://www.villycustoms.com/custom-builder/

Is there any Magento or Wordpress extension can do ?

Concept is customer need to pick up part of product style step by step.

Suppose Bicycle Product

customer need to choose style(color and patter style) of 8 parts (8 steps). step by step STEPS:

1. Frames
2. Tires
3. Wheels
4. Pedals
5. Chains
6. Accent
7. Seats
8. Grips

Each of step customer need to pick up some color style, pattern and that style will appear on product image also price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dunno if there is an exact similar as the provided link. But I have seen a similar extension for magento but its a paid one

www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-designer-fully-customizable.html

www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/pdp-online-products-designer-tool.html

productsdesignercanvas.com

I hope these will be of any help for u. I have not seen any free ones of this kind.

Answer (score 0):

I've searched some variants, and I think you may try this one: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dynamic-product-options.html

Answer (score 0):

With ever-changing trends and preferences of customers, it becomes necessary to provide that extra bit to them to retain them to your brand. More options the customers get, more time they will spend on your site. So this is an all-encompassing solution which is an addition to what Magento provides by default. ‘[Advanced Custom Option Extension for Magento 2](https://shop.emiprotechnologies.com/advanced-custom-options-suite-for-magento-2.html)’ is an extension rich with various functionalities which will not just save your time but also your efforts and save you from the hassles of those tedious tasks.

The extension is designed in a manner that you can create and manage product custom options in bulk and upload the suitable images in custom options. You can manage custom options for bulk products, manage dependency between options and many more functionalities to represent the image in custom options. I hope this will help you,

Thanks.